# Path of XML file in Resources folder to FileStream in C# WPF project

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, filestream

In a simple WPF project I have an XML file-"Students.xml" to view and add records. XML file is located in project's Resources folder with properties **Build Action : Resource** and **Copy always**. I can read the XML using:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.Students);
```

But for writing to it, FileStream requires its path in string.

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(Properties.Resources.Students, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
 // exception in first argument, string path should be specified.
```

So, how should I access xml file from resource folder in FileStream. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! I just added the file in the project and also copied that file in project's debug folder as well. Now I can simply access "filename.xml".

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Students.xml");
  /...../
 FileStream fs = new FileStream("Students.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

Now,its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [Resource File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494(v=vs.110).aspx), then its contents are *embedded* into the assembly, so there is no file path for them. Instead, you should add a folder named `Resources` into your project and add the XML file in there. If you do that, then you can access it using this property:

```
public static string ResourceFolderPath
{
    get
    {
        string path, applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        if (applicationDirectory.Contains(Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))) path = Path.Combine(
            applicationDirectory, "Resources");
        else path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(applicationDirectory).Parent.
            FullName, "Resources");
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to leave a comment down voters? It's otherwise pointless down voting.